# thread was being aborted web service in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sitecore, sitecore8

In my `WebService` I have a `WebMethod`. This method contains a `foreach` loop, where I'm looping thousands of records and adding to `Sitecore` and then writing to a log.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
   public int Copy()
   {
     foreach (Item item in subItems)  //subitems are around 1L
      {
         CopyLanguage();
      }
   }
```

Code for Copying data (Exception caught in this method)

```
   private void CopyLanguage()
   {
      string message = "success";
      using (new SecurityDisabler())
      {
        try
        {
          //Copying Data
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           message = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
         Log(message);
        }
      }
   }
```

**Copying Data**

```
void Copy(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Globalization.Language sourceLanguage,
             Sitecore.Globalization.Language targetLanguage)
        {
            //get a reference to the master DB
            Sitecore.Data.Database masterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item targetItem = masterDB.Items[item.ID, targetLanguage];
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sourceItem = masterDB.Items[item.ID, sourceLanguage];

            if (targetItem == null || sourceItem == null || sourceItem.Versions.Count == 0)
                return;
            //Disable the security context
            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (targetItem.Versions.Count == 0)
                    {
                  //add a version if none exist
                        targetItem = targetItem.Versions.AddVersion();
                    }
                    //edit item in target language
                    targetItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                    sourceItem.Fields.ReadAll();
                    //copy over all fields from source to target language
                    //we omit internal fields which start with __
                    foreach (Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field in sourceItem.Fields)
                    {
                        if (!field.Shared && !field.Name.StartsWith("__") && field.Name.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            targetItem.Fields[field.Name].SetValue(field.Value, true);
                        }
                    }

                    targetItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                    targetItem.Editing.AcceptChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    targetItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
                }
            }
```

Writing Log file file

```
private void Log(string message)
{
   // Writing Log to text file
}
```

The log file is printing "success" but after a while throwing an error

**Error :**

> Thread was being aborted

**StackTrace**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_SqlDbType(SqlDbType value)
>   at Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerDataApi.CreateParameter(String
>   name, Object value)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateCommand(String sql,
>   Object[] parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__10()

I have searched in Stackoverflow and got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412866/webservice-call-exception-thread-was-being-aborted).
Here I have to loop through in the service itself.

I have tried the second option by setting

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="600"/>
```

his hasn't helped me out.

Is there a way to resolve the issue or to continue the loop after the exception

Comment: So it is erroring out inside the service rather than where the service is being called?

Comment: are you using datareader or dataset?

Comment: @riteshmeher I have simplified the code.This is not from `datareader` or `dataset` but from `Sitecore`.

Comment: @Adam Yes, the error as thrown at the `Service` and the called method having no clue whats going on.

Comment: Why is the thread being aborted? In a web application or service this happens if the request finishes or a timeout occurs. What does the code in ` //Copying Data` do ? Are you starting any background Tasks that didn't finish? Any `async void` methods?

Comment: Also log the *full* exception, including its callstack, not just the message. Just call `ex.ToString()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited my question with the Copying Data method

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik please update your question with the full exception information. Do a `ex.ToString()` and give us the full output of that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have a really bad internet connection right now. If you don't mind I will post tomorrow early hours

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadAbortException` is a special exception that is automatically rethrown at the end of every catch block, unless you call `Thread.ResetAbort()`.
Try to call `Thread.ResetAbort()` in the catch block.

Comment: After adding `Thread.ResetAbort()`, I'm not getting the `error` but it has stopped working

Comment: Yes,after the 'ResrtAbort` method called,I feel there is no processing going on.

Comment: No its not.If you dont use Thread.ResetAbort() .net will throw error when maximum Error count exceeded you catch which are doesnt thrown.this function just seting error count to "0"  on current thread.

Comment: Then why do you think my `foreach` loop stopped after some point(I feel after the exception caught and `ResetAbort` called)

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    // will throw parse error
                    int.Parse("asdasd");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log The Exception
                    Logger.Log(ex);
                    Thread.ResetAbort();
                }
            }

Try this loop for check if stoping after some point.it will not stop.

Comment: `ResetAbort` will only *hide* the error, it won't fix anything. If a request terminates or it times out, its thread *will* be aborted and nothing can prevent this. Worst case is that some code will abort, some will keep executing and possibly cause serious corruption

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's what happening in my case. Is there a way sort out this error.

Comment: It could be that you are running ResetAbort for all kinds of exceptions, not just ThreadAbortException.